# Hello World x86_64. Is this 100% correct?

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, att, gnu-assembler

I'm on an Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 system, kernel 6.5.0-15-generic.
I'm learning how to make simple programs that make system calls by using GAS AT&T assembly format.
This assembly program is in the file `hello.s`:

```
.section .rodata
msg: .ascii "Hello, World!\n"
.set msglen, (. - msg)

.section .text 
.global main
main:
  mov $1, %rax
  mov $1, %rdi 
  lea msg(%rip), %rsi 
  mov $msglen, %rdx
  syscall

  mov $60, %rax
  mov $0, %rdi 
  syscall
```

The way I obtain the executable is this:

- I assemble to get the object file with `as hello.s -o hello.o`
- I link to get the executable with `gcc hello.o -o hello`

The program works fine. I just have some doubts about the following:

1. What if I had used a file named `hello.S` instead of `hello.s`? Would it have been different doing something like:

   ```
   as hello.S -o hello.o
   gcc hello.o -o hello
   ```

   Are both forms correct?
2. Why is it that when I do something like `gcc -S demo.i` I get `demo.s` and not `demo.S`?
3. My goal was to create a simple classic main program in assembly that makes the write system call to write "Hello World". Is my code 100% correct?

Comment: As discussed [in comments under your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969835/how-do-i-go-about-creating-a-gas-att-format-main-assembly-program-that-uses-the), yes, `.s` is correct, although I'd recommend using `.S` for hand-written asm source to distinguish it from compiler temporaries (which are always `.s`, not C-preprocessor + asm).  And so you can `#include <asm/unistd.h>` and use `mov $__NR_write, %eax`.

Comment: And yes, your modifications to the source are what I described in my answer on your last question.  I don't see any correctness problems here, only efficiency (e.g. mov instead of `xor %edi, %edi` to zero it, and using 64-bit operand-size, 7-byte `mov $sign_extended_imm32, %r64` is larger than 5-byte `mov $imm32, %r32` which implicitly zero-extends.  For the file descriptor, the C arg is `int fd` so even if you're avoiding optimizations, 32-bit is the right operand-size to match the arg's type.  Other than the pointer, everything else is a small integer.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes, why is it that I usually see something like "movl" , "popq" or "leaq" instead of "mov","pop" or "lea" when I examine the assembly files obtained from "gcc -S demo.i" ? In my Hello World program I didn't specify these suffixes so I guess it defaults to some values. What exactly ?

Comment: Probably ask a new question specifically about that rather than demand more information from a specific user (but as always, search before asking, and include information about your own reseach if you end up posting a new question).

Comment: ... But somewhat predictably, this was literally my top seach hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694701/the-difference-between-mov-and-movl-instruction-in-x86-and-i-meet-some-trouble

Comment: @Kode1000: Compilers always print the operand-size suffix whether it's redundant or not.  It's easier and more efficient for them to just do that than to check whether there's a register operand to imply a size.  `%rax` is a 64-bit register, so `mov $1, %rax` has 64-bit operand-size.  `mov $1, %eax` has 32-bit operand-size.  In x86-64, there are different names for each width of register, unlike e.g. ARM where a `strh` store-half-word or `strb` store-byte uses the same register name as for `str` store full register.

Comment: @PeterCordes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980526/gnu-c-library-assembly-syscall-source-files-location?noredirect=1#comment137476985_77980526

Answer (score 1):

You can also assemble and link your file in one shot by just doing `gcc -o hello hello.s`.

And this is related to your question.  `gcc` looks at input file suffixes to decide how to handle them.  A `.s` file gets fed directly to the assembler.  If it is named `.S` instead, then it gets filtered through the C preprocessor and then fed to the assembler.

So, if you would like to use C preprocessor features in your assembly source code (e.g. `#define`), then name your file with `.S` and use `gcc` (or `clang`) to build it.  If you don't want that feature, then keep using `.s`.

The compiler generates assembly that can go straight to the assembler without needing further preprocessing, so its assembly output files are named `.s` rather than `.S`.

Your code itself looks fine as far as correct operation.  There are some things you could improve related to efficiency.

- Most x86-64 instructions with 64-bit operands are one byte longer than their 32-bit counterparts, due to the need for a REX prefix byte.  So often it is preferable to use the 32-bit form instead when it will work, and take advantage of the fact that an instruction with a 32-bit register destination operand will automatically zero-extend it to 64 bits.  ([Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6))   Thus `mov $1, %eax` is exactly equivalent to `mov $1, %rax`, but the former is preferred because it saves one byte of code size.
- Zeroing a register is more efficient with `xor %edi, %edi` (which, as noted above, actually zeros all of `%rdi`).  [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)